# Android permission: Read device state and identity is shown

Tags: android, android-permissions

In my app I have used below two permissions only.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

But whenever I update the app to the newer version it shows "read device state and identity" permission as a new permission.

I am using android design library, swipelistview, numberpicker library and scrollpicker lib. I have also checked in those libraries. There is no `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. I am sure I don't need this permission for my app. How to resolve this issue?

Note: My app's `minSdkVersion = 14` & `targetSDKVersion=22`

Comment: have you used any third party library or jar file?

Comment: Try to check the generated manifest file and see if the permission exist and later try to search the whole project for that permission

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar, Thanks for the key point. Please find my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause for this issue. I am using scrollpicker thirdparty library. This library uses `minSdkVersion=3`. If the `minSdkVersion<=3` & `targetSdkVersion<=3` then android grant this permission to your app implicitly.

Please refer below the android docs,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#DONUT

So, when you start using any thirdparty libraries make sure that `minSdkVersion >=4` & `targetSdkVersion >=4`.